# How to fit model to data without noise (perfect fit) in R?

Tags: r

If I have the following dataset:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 3 + 4 * exp(x = 1:10))
```

And I try to fit a `nls` model:

```
nls(y ~ a + b * exp(x), data = df, start = list(a = 3.4, b = 4.1))
```

I get an error because this is a perfect fit and `nls` can't work with noiseless data (as shown in the function's examples). Is there an alternative function I can use that will find the parameters when a perfect fit is present?

Right now, all I know to do is put the data in Excel and create a "Chart" and show the trendline! I'd much rather do this straight in R.

Seems like a simple solution is possible, but I've searched around and haven't seen a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model is linear on `exp(x)` you can just run a simple linear regression:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 3 + 4 * exp(x = 1:10))
lm(y ~ exp(x), data  = df)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ exp(x), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       exp(x)  
          3            4
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer! This works for my particular problem currently. I'd appreciate knowing, however, if there's something out there for models where this work-around doesn't work.